# Delete Duplicate MySQL rows but keep one

Tags: mysql

I know this sounds like a duplicate question but I've read a bunch of others that seem related and still can't quite figure out what my statement should be. Hopefully my question isn't closed prematurely as a duplicate.

I have a table `calls` with a number of columns but the ones I want to use 3 columns to find exact matches: `call_start_date`, `call_from` and `call_to` and then use the column named `call_duration` to use as the deciding factor of whether or not to keep the row. Only the higher time in the `call_duration` should be kept.

This query works to find the duplicates but how do I modify this query to delete the lower-numbered `call_duration` results?

```
select t.*
from calls t join
 (select call_start_date, call_from, call_to, count(*) as NumDuplicates
  from calls
  group by call_start_date, call_from, call_to
  having NumDuplicates > 1
 ) tsum
 on t.call_start_date = tsum.call_start_date and t.call_from = tsum.call_from and t.call_to = tsum.call_to;
```

Here's my database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `calls` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`call_from` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`call_to` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`call_start_date` datetime NOT NULL,
`call_direction` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`user` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`queue_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
`call_duration` time DEFAULT NULL,
`call_result` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25001 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

This is a screenshot example of a duplicate. I just want to keep the one with the higher number in the `call_duration` column:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this for your select.  then just change the `select *` to `delete A` after confirming this gives the records you want to delete.

Think of it this way: you want a set of data with the max call duration Grouped by your 3 fields. Then, join this set on those 3 fields AND the max duration back to the base set to get all the unique calls joined to their max call duration.  Any records not matching that max duration would have a null join; and thus those are the ones you want to delete.

```
SELECT * 
FROM CALLS A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT call_from, call_to, Call_start_date, max(Call_Duration) mCD, min(ID) MID
            FROM calls
            GROUP BY call_from, call_to, Call_start_date) B
 on A.Call_from = B.call_from
and A.Call_to = B.call_to
and A.Call_start_date = B.call_Start_date
and A.call_duration = B.MCD
and A.ID = B.MID
WHERE B.mcd is null
```

So the delete would be: [UPDATED WORKING DEMO:](http://rextester.com/QMUD85073)

```
DELETE A
FROM CALLS A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT call_from, call_to, Call_start_date, max(Call_Duration) mCD, min(ID) mid
            FROM CALLS Z
            GROUP BY call_from, call_to, Call_start_date) B
 on A.Call_from = B.call_from
and A.Call_to = B.call_to
and A.Call_start_date = B.call_Start_date
and A.call_duration = B.MCD
and A.ID = B.MID
WHERE B.mcd is null;
```

Comment: Thanks, that queer seems to work for select but when I change `SELECT *` to `DELETE` in your query, I get an error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'A
LEFT JOIN (SELECT call_from, call_to, Call_start_date, max(Call_Duration) mCD' at line 2` I'm running MariaDB 10.2.9

Comment: `Delete` needs to be `Delete A` so it references the calls set (aliased A) containing all the records.  The working demo should help

Comment: Should note if there is more than 1 duplicate (for your unique 3 fields), it will get rid of all records except the one with the highest call duration.

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. Last question though: I'm seeing some cases where they have a duplicate `call_duration` which this doesn't seem to delete those. Could you modify the answer to delete those too?

Comment: does it matter which we keep?  the one with the smaller ID perhaps?

Comment: It doesn't matter. That's fine

Comment: We just extend the concept to add a unique field ID in this case so we can pick the smallest ID when that situation happens and add it to your join.  Answer updated as is the demo you may have to "Run it" again to see the 3 records; and then them getting reduced to one.  and sorry about my edit containing my example tablename: forgot to eliminate the SO46838117